# What is a good tool for mouse tracking?

Tags: usability-testing, user-research, tools

I would like to be able to track user activity on an HTML page.

What I want to achieve is the following, a breakdown of user activity per page, and a total time spent on the entire flow.

The information I want, is something similar to this:

**User ID:** [some number]

**Page 1:**
Pressed "btn-1" after 01:02 sec.
Pressed "btn-2" after 04:12 sec.
Pressed "next-btn" after 06:17 sec.
Total time: 06:17 sec

**Page 2:**
Pressed "btn-1" after 02:05 sec.
Pressed "next-btn" after 03:37 sec.
Total time: 03:37 sec

**Page 3:**
Pressed "btn-1" after 00:44 sec.
Pressed "btn-2" after 03:02 sec.
Pressed "next-btn" after 06:02 sec.
Total time: 06:02 sec

**All pages** - total time: 15:02

Does any of you have experience with something like this? Is Google Analytics a way to go about this, or should I do a custom session tracker in JS?

What are some recommended tools for gaining mouse tracking insights?

Comment: person who gave you -1 should at least explain why they did it... But I guess it's because this is not UX related question, it's a software question.

Comment: @Igor-G voting on questions / answers is anonymous, so although it is preferable for voters to give reasons there is no obligation / requirement to do so.

Comment: Whether or not tools-related questions are appropriate is currently being discussed on our [meta site](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/should-tool-related-questions-be-on-topic)

Comment: @JonW Yeah I know that, just saying that it would help. Kind of frustrating getting minuses not knowing what you did wrong.
Probably should have checked the FAQ

Comment: The FAQ isn't clear on this point

Comment: Does axure explort html/css/js sites, or what kind of prototype does it assemble? (Seems like a real interesting piece of software, btw!)

Comment: This may actually be a relevant question, but it really has nothing to do with Axure. It's a question about user research by mouse tracking.

Comment: @kontur Yes, Axure export the prototype you create in HTML/CSS/JS. So it's possible to add your own scripts by hand, after the prototype has been created by Axure.

Comment: Have you tried google analytics yet? It might require setting up some custom events and digging in a bit, but I think GA is by definition well suited to the task - I am thinking of user tracking/flow or inpage overlay here.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky Yes, you're right :) But it's not exactly mouse tracking that I'm looking for - there's tools out there, like ClickTale, that covers that very well. I do mobile prototypes, hence there's no mouse pointers in play.  What I'm after is something much more simple. I'm looking for a tool that allows me to document what has been clicked and at what time.

Comment: @kontur I'm familiar with the basics in Google Analytics. But I have to delve a bit more into it, to find out if it's possible to get stats similar to the example in my post.

Comment: @timkl Right, sorry, I forgot about the touch part... Feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Well, mixpanel will do most of what you want, but it's expensive, and in your case it would be fairly difficult to set up. Crazyegg will get you the clicks part, but I'm not sure if it can follow individual users through.

Answer (score 3):

One tool that gets good review on [24 Usability Testing Tools](http://www.usefulusability.com/24-usability-testing-tools/) is [**Simple Mouse Tracking (smt)**](http://smt.speedzinemedia.com/). It has a [long feature list](http://smt.speedzinemedia.com/features.php) and probably covers all the topics you have listed in your question:

> **Record mouse activity** on Web pages. This is a tool for webmasters, designers and everyone interested in how users use their Web interface.
>
> **Replay mouse activity** in real time. Watch the movements that people have done on your website. This system will replay them either in real time or as a static layer.

[image: Simple Mouse Tracking]